# LNK2019 errors while compiling through command line using msbuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

For the first time, I am trying to compile one of VC++ projects through command line using following command:

```
msbuild MyProject.vcproj
```

But I am getting many of

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol…
```

All these symbols are present in one library `*.lib` which is already compiled and present at the specified path. And if I build through VS IDE my project builds successfully without any `LNK2019` errors. But somehow during command line compilation it fails to link the library.

How can I resolve this and make it use the linked library during command line compile?

---

Command Line Options:

```
/Od /I "../" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "MYPROJECT_EXPORTS" /D "_WIN32_DCOM" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS" /D "_BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION=1" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0700" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"..\output\debug\x64\\" /Fd"..\output\debug\x64\vc90.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /Wp64 /Zi /TP /errorReport:prompt
```

Additional Options:

```
\Y-
```

Also I noticed one thing in the build log that it shows:

```
Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug|Win32 (TaskId:1)
Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug|x64 (TaskId:1)
Compiling... (TaskId:1)
cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Release|Win32 (TaskId:1)
  Compiling... (TaskId:1)
cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Release|x64 (TaskId:1)
```

I am confused why is it even trying to build any of `Win32` configuration as I want to build for x64 and using the respective `Visual Studio 2008 x64 Win64 Command Prompt`. Though not sure if this is causing my problem or not.

Comment: If it works fine from IDE then go to Project Properties -> Link -> Command Line and copy the correct command line option which includes the right *.lib files.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani that's of no use since the OP is building using msbuild, not invoking compiler/linker directly

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Done, please check.

Comment: What if you tell msbuild what you want instead of relying on some default, i.e. use msbuild MyProject.vcproj /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64?

Comment: @stijn Thankyou. This solved the issue. If you can post it as answer then i can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably started a 'visual studio command prompt for x64' (not sure of the exact name), but the default configuration/platform msbuild uses is Debug/Win32. It's hard to tell from the provided output what exactly happens next but it probably led to the linker looking for 32bit symbols in a 64bit library or vice versa - in any case, mixing platforms.

To fix this be specific in what you want to build, for example:

```
msbuild MyProject.vcproj /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64
```